# jquery drag and drop need explanation on if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone tell me why is this second if statement condition is met.

I checked the length of .correct and .drop using alert box and the length of .correct was 8 and the length of .drop was 5. But when i drag an image and drop it then the second if statement was working, it doesn't make sense. Here is fiddle http://fiddle.jshell.net/lawnyan/remaak5k/. It didn't work in fiddle. I think the framework in fiddle has a problem. Here is the website http://matchinggame.esy.es/game/Midterm.html

I need to explain all of the code and I can except the stop: fucntion if statement. Here is the code

```
 $("#car").draggable({
 start: function(event, ui) {
if (!done) return false;
 },
 stop: function(event, ui) {
 if ($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#win').text(winner +' '+ 'stars' + ' ' + 'earned');
     }
    }
 }
 });

 // for droppable...
 $("#carDrop").droppable({
 accept: "#car",
 drop: function(event, ui) {
 if(ui.draggable.is("#car")){
    $(this).addClass("correct");

    ui.draggable.fadeOut(500);
    $(this).fadeOut(500,function(){

     });
  }
 }
});
```

Please answer it I've been asking this question for 2 weeks and no one is answering

Comment: It looks like there are syntax errors in the code, `setTimeout` call is not proper. You haven't provided a time.

Comment: you can see the whole code on fiddl